# Why is my blade template syntax not working in my php file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have installed laravel correctly but when i try to run the following code in my php file, its not showing in my page:

```
@if(Route::has('login'))
    @auth
        @if(Auth::user()->utype === 'ADM')
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children parent" >
            <a title="My Account" href="#">My Account ({{Auth::user()->name}})<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="submenu curency" >
                <li class="menu-item" >
                    <a title="Dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children parent" >
            <a title="My Account" href="#">My Account ({{Auth::user()->name}})<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="submenu curency" >
                <li class="menu-item" >
                    <a title="Dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        @endif
    @else
        <li class="menu-item" ><a title="Register or Login" href="{{route('login')}}">Login</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item" ><a title="Register or Login" href="{{route('register')}}">Register</a></li>
    @endif

@endif
```

Comment: "_its not showing in my page_" And what _is_ showing instead? Did you name your file `.blade.php`? Do you have `login` route?

Comment: Yea I did name it blade.php and yes I made login route

Comment: If you know you have a route named `login`, then why have the first if-statement checking if it exists?

Comment: fyi, your HTML inside `@if(Auth::user()->utype === 'ADM')` and the `@else` part are the same

Comment: Try @dump(Route::has('login')) to check if is true. A false condition won't show anything.